# Can't install PostgreSQL 9 server on Centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, postgresql

Can't install PostgreSQL server on Centos Machine.

I simply added official repo with PostgreSQL

```
rpm -ivh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-3.noarch.rpm
```

And then ran

```
yum install yum install postgresql95-server
```

Here is the error i am getting:

```
Error unpacking rpm package postgresql95-server-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /var/lib/pgsql: cpio: stat
```

I have tried PostgreSQL 9.4, 9.5, 9.6 and they all have same error.

Also other packages from this repo are installing without any problem

Does anybody know what is the problem here?

Comment: Give us a bit more to work with.  Show us what command you typed to produce this output, as well as the output.  If you're installing a single rpm directly, tell us where you got it, and how; if via yum, how did you add the repo?  Do you already have any postgres packages installed?

Comment: I've updated my question with my steps. I don't have any other postgres packages installed.

Comment: Should we assume that the doubled `yum install` is a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the package locally, then install.  But pay attention to the version you are downloading.

> Quoted from https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/
>
> ```
> Distribution      Version
> ```
>
> ```
> RHEL/CentOS/SL/OL 7 9.2
> ```
>
> ```
> RHEL/CentOS/SL/OL 6 8.4
> ```
>
> ```
> RHEL/CentOS/SL/OL 5 8.1
> ```

*Sorry about the formatting for the above.  It is the best I can do with the limited tools we have here.*

Comment: That's great, but the OP says he wants PG9, on C6.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are root and don't have any selinux issues, you probably have some previously remaining files on the system where yum tries to install postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done what you said you did, on a clean C6 install, and it worked fine:

```
[me@angband ~]$ sudo rpm -ivh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-3.noarch.rpm
Retrieving https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-3.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.YH2GD1: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 442df0f8: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:pgdg-centos95          ########################################### [100%]
[me@angband ~]$ sudo yum install postgresql95-server
[...]
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql95-server.x86_64 0:9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql95-libs(x86-64) = 9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6 for package: postgresql95-server-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql95(x86-64) = 9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6 for package: postgresql95-server-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql95 = 9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6 for package: postgresql95-server-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql95.x86_64 0:9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6 will be installed
---> Package postgresql95-libs.x86_64 0:9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                Version                         Repository           Size
================================================================================================================
Installing:
 postgresql95-server              x86_64              9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6               pgdg95              4.5 M
Installing for dependencies:
 postgresql95                     x86_64              9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6               pgdg95              1.3 M
 postgresql95-libs                x86_64              9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6               pgdg95              208 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================
Install       3 Package(s)

Total download size: 6.0 M
Installed size: 24 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
[...]
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
  Installing : postgresql95-libs-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                   1/3 
  Installing : postgresql95-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                        2/3 
  Installing : postgresql95-server-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                 3/3 
  Verifying  : postgresql95-libs-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                   1/3 
  Verifying  : postgresql95-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                        2/3 
  Verifying  : postgresql95-server-9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                 3/3 

Installed:
  postgresql95-server.x86_64 0:9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6                                                                

Dependency Installed:
  postgresql95.x86_64 0:9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6              postgresql95-libs.x86_64 0:9.5.9-1PGDG.rhel6             

Complete!
```

So I don't think you're trying to do anything bonkers, and it seems likeliest that the RPM got in some way altered in transit, or your RPM environment is nonfunctional.  Are you using any kind of proxy for web access, and confirm that the error persists after a `yum clean all`?  And could you try installing a very small and harmless RPM, say `yum install rcs`, and see if that also fails?